# Why is my jumbotron not the same width as my responsive table in the panel beneath?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[Here's my layout sample on bootply](https://www.bootply.com/q3lrtlgLTC)

Does this require a CSS 'hack' or did I get my markup wrong to begin with?
(or, is this the default intended Twitter bootstrap design)?

Comment: I have looked at your Bootply and I'm still unsure of what you mean. What were you expecting?

Comment: My question is completely valid, thanks for downvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the jumbotron in a row div:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="jumbotron">
     .....
     .....
   </div>
</div>
```

OR use css to increase the width and adjust the position like:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="width:102%; margin-left:-1%">
  ....
  ....
</div>
```

(not recommended)

Comment: You and @ProEvilz both pointed me to the same answer, but, your code snippet seems to show this in the cleanest manner.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a default Jumbotron looks like. I'm not sure why you didn't just check the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#jumbotron) to see their basic example?

**Edit:** The reason why your Jumbotron isn't the same width is because your table is wrapped in a `.row` class which has `margin-left: -15px` & `margin-right: -15px` applied to it.

To fix your issue, wrap your `.jumbotron` in a `<div class="row"></div>`

You should always place your elements within a column though. e.g. `.row > .col-sm-12 > .jumbotron`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <p>This is a lead</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I checked the defaults shown in the docs, which I don't think give an example of a jumbotron positioned over a responsive table - thus my question